# map mode button in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, dictionary, switch-statement, mode

I'm trying to make an ApplicationBarMenuItem that, when clicked, switches my bing map between RoadMode and AerialMode. my pseudocode looks something like this:

```
private void changeMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(map1.Mode == RoadMode)
           map1.Mode = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.AerialMode();
        else
           map1.Mode = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.RoadMode();
    }
```

However, it says I cannot use RoadMode, which is a 'type', like a variable. Does anyone have a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because RoadMode is a class and you are trying to compare class to an object.

Try (edit)

```
if(map1.Mode is RoadMode)
```

Comment: when I do that, I get this message:


Error 6 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.MapMode' and 'System.Type'

Comment: Do you have added usings? try what changed or (map1.Mode is Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.RoadMode)